# Is there any benefit of combing Instance Meshing with quadtrees LoD?

Tags: procedural-generation, optimization, instancing, level-of-detail, quadtree

I would like to know if there would be any benefit of combing Instance Meshing with quadtrees LoD? Besides the obvious performance improvement of only having one mesh

I wanted to try and implement Instance Meshing with quadtrees LoD for my planet rendering. But it seems redundant now that I think about it. Because if I have one high-resolution Instance Mesh that creates multiple instance quad for my planet then I don't need a quadtree data structure that shows only the relevant subdivide part to the camera based on the user's position. Wouldn't that 1 high-resolution Instance Mesh all I would need? I can create multiple instances from it and offset my planet texture to give each instance its own part.

If anyone has any insight into this it would be a big help before going down this road.

Comment: The best way to answer a question like this is to try it and profile the result. It's not immediately clear to me which two implementations you want to compare, so there's a chance I could give you a misleading answer. But with profiling, you get measurable proof what answer is right for your exact implementation, running with your game's exact context and workload.

Comment: @DMGregory well, it's really not about comparing instance mesh vs quadtree-LoD for planet rendering but if combining them would make sense.  and I didn't just waste my time.

Comment: You've thought of a way to do it. What problem do you perceive with that way? You might want to try adding a diagram to your question, showing what you plan to do with the mesh instances if they're not arranged in a quadtree.